# insert or ignore rows that violate foreign key constraints sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert many rows into my table, some of which violate a foreign key constraint on that table. I want to SKIP adding the rows that violate this constraint and add all the correct rows successfully. However, I get an error even if I use `insert or ignore` in my query.

Is there any way to do this in SQLite?

Comment: NO, this is what a foreign key make of. To stop you from adding data that isn't right and might potentially ruin the database

Comment: Perhaps I under-specified the question @T.Peter. I wish to ignore these rows and *not* insert them.

Comment: `ignore` only work with pk or unique constraint if I recall, with fk it will work like abort.

Comment: you can work around by using `exists` to check if the row violate fk before insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to filter in the `insert` statement:

```
insert into table2 ( . . . )
    select . . . 
    from table1 t1
    where exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.pk = t1.t2pk
                 );
```

That is, don't even attempt the insert.